# read json object and create csv string from it in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

read json object and create csv string from it in python.

I have a object array in string format as.

```
'[{"date":"2014-10-05T01:12:00.000Z","count":56.4691}, {"date":"2014-10-05T01:14:00.000Z","count":23.4691}, ...]'
```

I want to transform the string into csv format as,

```
"","date","count"
"1",2014-09-25 14:01:00,182.478
"2",2014-09-25 14:01:00,182.478
```

to be able to do it, I firstly read the string with `read_json` function in `pandas` library. but it sorted the columns. and `count` column comes before the `date` column. how can i get this transformation in python?

Answer (score 1):

Use `columns` parameter in `df.to_csv`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

s = '[{"date":"2014-10-05T01:12:00.000Z","count":56.4691}, {"date":"2014-10-05T01:14:00.000Z","count":23.4691}]'

df = pd.read_json(s)
df.to_csv(r"PATH\B.csv", columns=["date", "count"])
```

Comment: thank you, but actually i don't want to store it as csv file. i just want it in a string format.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(s), columns=["date", "count"])
print(df)` ?